# JMeter/Timeshift: Using timeShift, get UTC time without converting to local time. eg. ${__timeShift(HH:mm,,PT30M,,)}

Tags: java, jmeter, timeshift

Whenever I run `${__timeShift(HH:mm,,PT30M,,)}` from the Function Helper, it gives me the time in CST (my local timezone)

I'm having trouble figuring out how to use timeShift to evaluate the HH:mm value **without automatically converting it to CST time.** Is there a simple way to do this, or will I need to use to use a JSR223 process to calculate the UTC value and vars.put it as a variable?

The ultimate goal is to use this value in an HTTP Sampler.

I've tried various combinations of parameters from the https://www.perfmatrix.com/jmeter-timestamp/

Also tried some basic time conversions in a JSR223 process. I am extremely new to both Java and JMeter though, so I haven't had much success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer was to set a default time zone:

`TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone('UTC'))`

`def theTime = ${__timeShift("HH:mm",,PT30M,,)}`

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this using the following scary [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy):

```
${__groovy(java.time.ZonedDateTime.now(java.time.ZoneId.of("UTC")).plusMinutes(30).format(java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm")),)}
```

More information: [The Groovy Templates Cheat Sheet for JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-templates)

Comment: I do not have experience with groovy; therefore, I can not comment on the groovy part. This comment is about introducing the modern date-rime API, `java.time` API. Good job! A bit cleaner code would be using `java.time.OffsetDateTime.now(java.time.ZoneOffset.UTC)`.